# Remove each element that is the last value based on a unique ID

Tags: r

So what I would like to do is to remove each element that is the last value based on the ID. I have a fairly large data set, so it would not be optimal to do it by hand.

Here are some sample values.

```
ID <- c(1, 1, 1, 231313, 231313, 45, 45, 89, 89, 89, 89)
distance <- c(0.3, 1.2, 0.8, 0.5, 6789, 0.1, 349495, 0.1, 0.3, 0.9, 49494)
data <- data.frame(ID = ID, distance = distance)
```

To make it more clear, I would like to remove 0.8, 6789, 349495 and 49494  with "" since they are the last value for each unique ID.

The results would look like this:

```
ID      distance
1       0.3
1       1.2
1
231313  0.5
231313
45      0.1
45
89      0.1
89      0.3
89      0.9
89
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally not a good idea to use "" as 'missing' (e.g., it coerces numeric values to character strings). Base R functionality finds those that are not duplicated (starting from the end), and updates the corresponding column

```
> data[!duplicated(data$ID, fromLast=TRUE), "distance"] = NA
> data
       ID distance
1       1      0.3
2       1      1.2
3       1       NA
4  231313      0.5
5  231313       NA
6      45      0.1
7      45       NA
8      89      0.1
9      89      0.3
10     89      0.9
11     89       NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a `''` and changing the column `class` from `numeric` to `character`, we can replace the last value per each 'ID' as `NA`.  Using `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(data)`), get the row index (`.I`) of last row (`.N`) for each 'ID', we assign the 'distance' corresponding to that rows as 'NA'.

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(data)[, .I[.N], ID]$V1
data[i1, distance:= NA_real_]
data
#        ID distance
# 1:      1      0.3
# 2:      1      1.2
# 3:      1       NA
# 4: 231313      0.5
# 5: 231313       NA
# 6:     45      0.1
# 7:     45       NA
# 8:     89      0.1
# 9:     89      0.3
#10:     89      0.9
#11:     89       NA
```

---

Or we can do this in a single step

```
setDT(data)[1:.N ==.N , distance:= NA_real_ ,ID]
```